# Kitchen and Kitchen-docker

Tags: docker, chef-infra, test-kitchen

I am trying to use [kitchen-docker](https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-docker) driver on a GNU/Linux machine. I have installed the `kitchen-docker` gem using `chef gem install` command.

This is an extract of my `.kitchen.yml` file:

```
---
driver:
  name: docker

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero

verifier:
  name: inspec

platforms:
  - name: centos-7.2
    driver_config:
      image: centos:7.2
      platform: centos

suites:
  - name: zaz
    run_list:
      - recipe[foo::bar]
...
...
```

I have `Docker` installed on it's latest version using Docker repositories for Centos. The service is running and `Docker` is in my path. However when I try to run a simple `kitchen list` using that `.kitchen.yml` I get this error:

```
[FakeyMcFakeFace@workstation foo]$ kitchen list
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::UserError
>>>>>> Message: You must first install the Docker CLI tool http://www.docker.io/gettingstarted/
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration
```

Why is docker not being recognized by Kitchen? If I run the `diagnose -all` option I just see it is failing on the dependencies check:

```
backtrace:
- "/home/FakeyMcFakeFace/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/kitchen-docker-2.6.0/lib/kitchen/driver/docker.rb:93:in
  `rescue in verify_dependencies'"
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is your user allowed to access the docker socket? (Does `docker ps` work?).  Or do you run it with `sudo docker ps`? In the first case, try to set `use_sudo: false`, as I would then assume that you don't have sudo installed and kitchen-docker assumes it's available.

Comment: Docker is run as root, so `sudo` is needed for all commands. The default `use_sudo: true` is good for me. Also I have the default socket location... it should be accessible naturally.

Comment: Anything useful from `-l debug`?

Comment: Seems like kitchen-docker **requires** passwordless `sudo`... is this undocumented or I just misread something?

Comment: How would it use anything other than passwordless sudo?

Comment: Requesting password during kitchen run instead of failing or giving some useful data in the error message :-/

Comment: Unfortunately it's very tricky to pass an external password in to sudo so it's going to be a low priority thing.

Comment: But yes, I do need to fix the diagnostics to better detect which part is failing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy down from the comments, kitchen-docker requires passwordless sudo (if using sudo) right now, the error message is misleading